# ANTLR + Scala : ideas for improvements?

Tags: java, scala, antlr4

I'm trying to find a way to integrate an antlr parser in the realm of Scala.

I've tried visitors coded in scala to build scala objects from the parse tree, but the restriction to have a uniform return type is a no go.

So I took the plunge and decided to build scala objects directly from parser actions  using the java interface of the scala classes.

This blog post was of great help:

http://blog.akquinet.de/2011/07/20/integrating-scala-components-in-a-java-application/

Here is what I have obtained:

The scala AST DSL

```
package toylang.ast

trait TypeExpr
case object IntType extends TypeExpr
case object BoolType extends TypeExpr

trait Expr
case class Ident(name: String) extends Expr
case class IntNum(repr: String) extends Expr
case object True extends Expr
case object False extends Expr
case class Plus(e: Expr) extends Expr
case class Minus(e: Expr) extends Expr
case class Add(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Sub(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Mul(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Div(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Pow(e: Expr, exponent: Expr) extends Expr
case class Not(e: Expr) extends Expr
case class And(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Or(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Implies(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr

case class Ite(c: Expr, t: Expr, eif: List[Elsif], e:Expr) extends Expr
case class Elsif(c: Expr, t: Expr) 

case class Neq(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Eq(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Lt(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Le(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Gt(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Ge(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr

trait Stmt
case class DefStmt(id: Ident, t: TypeExpr, e: Expr) extends Stmt
```

The antlr grammar with java actions calling scala constructors

```
grammar ToyLang;

// lexer customized header
@lexer::header{
package toylang.parser.antlr;
}

// parser customized header
@parser::header{
package toylang.parser.antlr;
import toylang.ast.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import utils.Fun;
import utils.Conv;
}

@parser::members {

// a class which extracts an object from a context an can be mapped over a java list.
Fun defStmtMap = new Fun<DefStmtContext, Stmt> () {
    public Stmt apply(DefStmtContext ctx) {
        return ctx.result;
    }
};

// a class which extracts an object from a context an can be mapped over a java list.
Fun elsifMap = new Fun<ElsifContext, Elsif> () {
    public Elsif apply(ElsifContext ctx) {
        return ctx.result;
    }
};

}

program returns [scala.collection.immutable.List<Stmt> result]
    : sl+=defStmt sl+=defStmt* EOF { 
            $result = Conv.scalaList(Conv.map($sl, defStmtMap)); 
        }
    ;

type returns[TypeExpr result]
    : 'int'  { $result = IntType$.MODULE$; }
    | 'bool' { $result = IntType$.MODULE$; }
    ;

defStmt returns[Stmt result]
    : id=ident ':' t=type  op=DEFINE e=expr ';' { 
            $result = DefStmt$.MODULE$.apply($id.ctx.result, $t.ctx.result, $e.ctx.result); 
        }
    ; 

expr returns[Expr result]
    : lit=TRUE
        { $result = True$.MODULE$; }

    | lit=FALSE
        { $result = False$.MODULE$; }                        

    | lit=INT_LIT
        { $result = IntNum$.MODULE$.apply($lit.text); }        

    | id=ident
        { $result = $id.ctx.result; }

    | op='(' e=expr ')'
        { $result = $e.ctx.result; }

    | IF c=expr THEN t=expr ei+=elsif* ELSE e=expr 
        {
            scala.collection.immutable.List<Elsif> l = Conv.scalaList(Conv.map($ei, elsifMap)); 
            $result = Ite$.MODULE$.apply($c.ctx.result, $t.ctx.result, l, $e.ctx.result);
        }

    | op=(ADD|SUB) e=expr
        { 
            switch($op.type) {
                case ADD : $result = Plus$.MODULE$.apply($e.ctx.result); break;  
                case SUB : $result = Minus$.MODULE$.apply($e.ctx.result); break;  
            }
        }

    |<assoc=right> l=expr op=CARRET r=expr  
        { $result = Pow$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); }

    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=(STAR|SLASH) r=expr  
        { 
            switch($op.type) {
                case STAR : $result = Mul$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
                case SLASH : $result = Div$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
            }
        }
    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=(ADD|SUB) r=expr 
        {
            switch($op.type) {
                case ADD : $result = Add$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
                case SUB : $result = Sub$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
            }
        }
    | l=expr op=(NEQ|EQ|LT|LE|GT|GE) r=expr
        {
            switch($op.type) {
                case NEQ : $result = Neq$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
                case EQ : $result = Eq$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
                case LT : $result = Lt$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
                case LE : $result = Le$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
                case GT : $result = Gt$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
                case GE : $result = Ge$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); break;  
            }
        }

    | op=NOT e=expr
        { $result = Not$.MODULE$.apply($e.ctx.result); }

    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=AND r=expr
        { $result = And$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); }

    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=OR r=expr
        { $result = Or$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); }

    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=IMPLIES r=expr
        { $result = Implies$.MODULE$.apply($l.ctx.result, $r.ctx.result); }
    ;

elsif returns[Elsif result]
    : op=ELSIF c=expr THEN t=expr 
        {
            $result = Elsif$.MODULE$.apply($c.ctx.result, $t.ctx.result);
        }
    ;

ident returns [Ident result]
        : IDENT { $result = Ident$.MODULE$.apply($IDENT.text); }
        ;
LT: '<' ;
LE: '<=' ;
GT: '>' ;
GE: '>=' ;
EQ: '=' ;
NEQ: '!=' ;
ADD: '+';
AND: 'and';
DEFINE: ':=';
CARRET: '^';
ELSE: 'else';
ELSIF: 'elsif';
FALSE: 'false';
IF: 'if';
IMPLIES: 'implies';
KW_BOOL: 'bool';
KW_INT: 'int';
NOT: 'not';
OR: 'or';
SLASH: '*';
STAR: '*';
SUB: '-';
THEN: 'then';
TRUE: 'true';

INT_LIT
    :'0' 
    |[1-9][0-9]*
    ; 

IDENT:[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*;
WS: [ \t\f\r\n]+ -> skip;
//NL: '\r'? \n;
```

And last the two java utility classes, Conv and Fun, Conv contain the code to convert a java list to a well typed scala list, Fun is an interface for actions that get mapped over the java list before conversion to a scala list.

```
package utils;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class Conv<A, B> {

    public static <T> scala.collection.immutable.List<T> scalaList(List<T> javaList) {
        return scala.collection.JavaConversions.iterableAsScalaIterable(javaList).toList();
    }

    public static <A,B> List<B> map(List<A> from, Fun<A,B> convert) {

        ArrayList<B> res = new ArrayList<B>();

        for (A fromElem : from) {
            res.add(convert.apply(fromElem));
        }
        return res;
    }   
}

package utils;

public interface Fun<A, B> {
    B apply(A input);
}
```

The scala code which calls the antlr parser:

```
package toylang.parser

import org.antlr.v4.runtime._
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree._
import org.stringtemplate.v4._
import toylang.parser.antlr._
import java.io.FileInputStream
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._


class Parser( arg: String ) {
  val input = new ANTLRInputStream(new FileInputStream(arg))
  val lexer = new ToyLangLexer(input)
  val tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer)
  val parser = new ToyLangParser(tokens)
  val prog = parser.program
  println (prog.result)
}
```

Any idea for improvement on the extract-results-from-contex-java-to-scala list conversion would be welcome. Making it fully generic would be great, perhaps using the java reflection API. Ideally I would like to use a single statement to say: extract field named 'foo' from each antlr rule context objects (or token) of this list and convert the result to a scala list.

I've looked all around the net and found no tuto on how to do that.

Regards,

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could also consider rather than using an ANTLR generated grammar using some of the other parser libraries, i.e. Parboiled (http://parboiled.org), Parboiled2 (https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2) or Parser combinators from the standard library.

Comment: Hi Martijn, 
I've never tried parboiled, I'll have a look at it, if speed and memory consumption are better than scala's combinators it could be a solution. 
Actually I am trying to move away from scala combinators, for performance reasons and readability/maintainability.
I also tried scala-bison, which is also quite nice, but I've never been good at resolving shift/reduce or reduce/reduce conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to give you a heads up, I've put together a hack to be able to embed scala actions directly in a g4 grammar.

[antlr2scala_v0.1.tar.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1HLL8ihEt_wY2h0clRub09teE0/view?usp=sharing)

I've modified the ANTLRv4Lexer.g4 and ANTLRv4Parser.g4 found here:

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr4

to allow special comments like this

```
//! <scala code>
```

to be added first in the file to define the scala listener's header,

just before the list of rules to define the scala listener's members,

and at right before or after rule alternatives, to specify enter and exit actions for each alternative (which must be labelled).

Based on this modified format I developped a tool which extracts and packages the code for a scala listener from the special comments.

In practice an extended file with scala actions looks like this:

```
//! // scala listener header
//! package toylang.parser.antlr
//! import toylang.ast._
//! import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

grammar ToyLang;

@lexer::header{
package toylang.parser.antlr;
}

@parser::header{
package toylang.parser.antlr;
import toylang.ast.*; // import scala ast symbols
}

//! // scala listener members
//! // stores the result of a successfull parse
//! var result: Option[List[Stmt]] = None 

program 
locals [scala.collection.immutable.List<Stmt> result]
    : sl+=defStmt sl+=defStmt* EOF # ProgramRule
        //! // exitAction for alternative
        //! ctx.result = (ctx.sl.view  map { _.result }).toList
        //! result = Some(ctx.result)

    ;

type 
locals [TypeExpr result]
    : 'int'  # IntType
        //! ctx.result = IntType
    | 'bool' # BoolType
        //! ctx.result = BoolType
    ;

defStmt 
locals[Stmt result]
    : 
        //! // entry action for alternative
        //! println("About to parse a statement!")
        //!
        id=ident ':' t=type  d=def? ';' # DefStmtRule
        //! // exit action for alternative
        //! val d = ctx.d match {
        //!   case null => None
        //!   case e@_ => Some(e.result)
        //! }
        //! ctx.result = DefStmt(ctx.id.result, ctx.t.result, d)
    ; 

def
locals [Expr result]
    : op=DEFINE e=expr  # DefRule
        //! ctx.result = ctx.e.result
    ;

expr 
locals[Expr result]
    : e=boolNum  # BoolNumExpr
        //! ctx.result = ctx.e.result

    | e=intNum   # IntNumxpr
        //! ctx.result = ctx.e.result

    | e=ident    # IdentExpr
        //! ctx.result = ctx.e.result

    | op='(' e=expr ')' # ParenExpr
        //! ctx.result = ctx.e.result

    | op=(ADD|SUB) e=expr # UnopArithExpr
        //! import ToyLangParser.{ADD, SUB}
        //!  val op = ctx.op.getType match {
        //!  case ADD => Plus
        //!  case SUB => Minus
        //! }
        //! ctx.result = op(ctx.e.result)

    |<assoc=right> l=expr op=CARRET r=expr  # PowerExpr
        //! ctx.result = Pow(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)

    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=(STAR|SLASH) r=expr # MulDivExpr
        //! import ToyLangParser.{STAR, SLASH}
        //!  val op = ctx.op.getType match {
        //!  case STAR => Mul
        //!  case SLASH => Div
        //! }
        //! ctx.result = op(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result) 

    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=(ADD|SUB) r=expr # AddSubExpr
        //! import ToyLangParser.{ADD, SUB}
        //!  val op = ctx.op.getType match {
        //!  case ADD => Add
        //!  case SUB => Sub
        //! }
        //! ctx.result = op(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result) 

    | l=expr op=(NEQ|EQ|LT|LE|GT|GE) r=expr # RelExpr
        //! import ToyLangParser.{NEQ,EQ,LT,LE,GT,GE}
        //!  val op = ctx.op.getType match {
        //!  case NEQ => Neq
        //!  case EQ => Eq
        //!  case LT => Lt
        //!  case GT => Gt
        //!  case LE => Le
        //!  case GE => Ge
        //! }
        //! ctx.result = op(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result) 

    | op=NOT e=expr   # NotExpr
        //! ctx.result = Not(ctx.e.result)

    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=AND r=expr # AndExpr
        //! ctx.result = And(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)

    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=OR r=expr  # OrExpr
        //! ctx.result = Or(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)

    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=IMPLIES r=expr # ImpliesExpr
        //! ctx.result = Implies(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)

    | IF c=expr THEN t=expr ei+=elsif* ELSE e=expr  # IteExpr
        //! val elsifList = ctx.ei.view  map { _.result } 
        //! ctx.result = Ite(ctx.c.result, 
        //!                  ctx.t.result, 
        //!                  elsifList.toList, 
        //!                  ctx.e.result)
   ;

elsif 
locals [Elsif result]
    : op=ELSIF c=expr THEN t=expr # ElsifRule
        //! ctx.result = Elsif(ctx.c.result, ctx.t.result)
    ;

ident
locals [Ident result]
    : id=IDENT # IdentRule
        //! ctx.result = Ident(ctx.id.getText)
    ;

intNum
locals [IntNum result]
    : num=INT_NUM # IntNumRule
        //! ctx.result = IntNum(ctx.num.getText)
    ;

boolNum
locals [BoolNum result]
    : num=(TRUE | FALSE) # BoolNumRule
        //! ctx.result = BoolNum(ctx.num.getText)

    ;

COMMENT: (EOL | MLC) -> skip ;
fragment MLC: '/*' ( COMMENT | . )*? '*/' ;
fragment EOL: '//' .*? '\n' ;

LT: '<' ;
LE: '<=' ;
GT: '>' ;
GE: '>=' ;
EQ: '=' ;
NEQ: '!=' ;
ADD: '+';
AND: 'and';
DEFINE: ':=';
CARRET: '^';
ELSE: 'else';
ELSIF: 'elsif';
FALSE: 'false';
IF: 'if';
IMPLIES: 'implies';
KW_BOOL: 'bool';
KW_INT: 'int';
NOT: 'not';
OR: 'or';
SLASH: '*';
STAR: '*';
SUB: '-';
THEN: 'then';
TRUE: 'true';
INT_NUM :'0' |[1-9][0-9]* ; 
IDENT:[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
WS: [ \t\f\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

The extracted listener looks like this:

```
// !!! DO NOT EDIT!!! 
// Code generated from grammar ToyLang by antlr4scala
// 

 // scala listener header
 package toylang.parser.antlr
 import toylang.ast._
 import scala.collection.JavaConversions._


class  Listener extends ToyLangBaseListener {

     // scala listener members
     // stores the result of a successfull parse
     var result: Option[List[Stmt]] = None 


    override def enterDefStmtRule( ctx: ToyLangParser.DefStmtRuleContext ): Unit = {
         // entry action for alternative
         println("About to parse a statement!")

    }


    override def exitProgramRule( ctx: ToyLangParser.ProgramRuleContext ): Unit = {
         // exitAction for alternative
         ctx.result = (ctx.sl.view  map { _.result }).toList
         result = Some(ctx.result)
    }


    override def exitIntType( ctx: ToyLangParser.IntTypeContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = IntType
    }


    override def exitBoolType( ctx: ToyLangParser.BoolTypeContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = BoolType
    }


    override def exitDefStmtRule( ctx: ToyLangParser.DefStmtRuleContext ): Unit = {
         // exit action for alternative
         val d = ctx.d match {
           case null => None
           case e@_ => Some(e.result)
         }
         ctx.result = DefStmt(ctx.id.result, ctx.t.result, d)
    }


    override def exitDefRule( ctx: ToyLangParser.DefRuleContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = ctx.e.result
    }


    override def exitBoolNumExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.BoolNumExprContext ): Unit = {
            ctx.result = ctx.e.result
    }


    override def exitIntNumxpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.IntNumxprContext ): Unit = {
            ctx.result = ctx.e.result
    }


    override def exitIdentExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.IdentExprContext ): Unit = {
            ctx.result = ctx.e.result
    }


    override def exitParenExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.ParenExprContext ): Unit = {
            ctx.result = ctx.e.result
    }


    override def exitUnopArithExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.UnopArithExprContext ): Unit = {
         import ToyLangParser.{ADD, SUB}
          val op = ctx.op.getType match {
          case ADD => Plus
          case SUB => Minus
         }
         ctx.result = op(ctx.e.result)
    }


    override def exitPowerExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.PowerExprContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = Pow(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
    }


    override def exitMulDivExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.MulDivExprContext ): Unit = {
         import ToyLangParser.{STAR, SLASH}
          val op = ctx.op.getType match {
          case STAR => Mul
          case SLASH => Div
         }
         ctx.result = op(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result) 
    }


    override def exitAddSubExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.AddSubExprContext ): Unit = {
         import ToyLangParser.{ADD, SUB}
          val op = ctx.op.getType match {
          case ADD => Add
          case SUB => Sub
         }
         ctx.result = op(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result) 
    }


    override def exitRelExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.RelExprContext ): Unit = {
         import ToyLangParser.{NEQ,EQ,LT,LE,GT,GE}
          val op = ctx.op.getType match {
          case NEQ => Neq
          case EQ => Eq
          case LT => Lt
          case GT => Gt
          case LE => Le
          case GE => Ge
         }
         ctx.result = op(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result) 
    }


    override def exitNotExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.NotExprContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = Not(ctx.e.result)
    }


    override def exitAndExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.AndExprContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = And(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
    }


    override def exitOrExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.OrExprContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = Or(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
    }


    override def exitImpliesExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.ImpliesExprContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = Implies(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
    }


    override def exitIteExpr( ctx: ToyLangParser.IteExprContext ): Unit = {
         val elsifList = ctx.ei.view  map { _.result } 
         ctx.result = Ite(ctx.c.result, 
                          ctx.t.result, 
                          elsifList.toList, 
                          ctx.e.result)
    }


    override def exitElsifRule( ctx: ToyLangParser.ElsifRuleContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = Elsif(ctx.c.result, ctx.t.result)
    }


    override def exitIdentRule( ctx: ToyLangParser.IdentRuleContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = Ident(ctx.id.getText)
    }


    override def exitIntNumRule( ctx: ToyLangParser.IntNumRuleContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = IntNum(ctx.num.getText)
    }


    override def exitBoolNumRule( ctx: ToyLangParser.BoolNumRuleContext ): Unit = {
         ctx.result = BoolNum(ctx.num.getText)
    }


}
```

The original ANTLR 4.4 can still be used to generate java lexers and parsers out of the extended g4 file, the generated listener can be attached to the java parser from within scala.

/Rémi

Answer (score 2):

The answer was under my eyes the whole time and I was too blind to see it: Listeners.

Updated grammar with locals definitions so that scala objects can be stored:

```
grammar ToyLang2;

@lexer::header{
package toylang.parser.antlr;
}

@parser::header{
package toylang.parser.antlr;
import toylang.ast.*; // import scala ast symbols
}

program 
locals [scala.collection.immutable.List<Stmt> result]
    : sl+=defStmt sl+=defStmt* EOF 
    ;

type 
locals [TypeExpr result]
    : 'int'  # IntType
    | 'bool' # BoolType
    ;

defStmt 
locals[Stmt result]
    : id=ident ':' t=type  d=def? ';'
    ; 

def
locals [Expr result]
    : op=DEFINE e=expr
    ;

expr 
locals[Expr result]
    : e=boolNum                                     #BoolNumExpr
    | e=intNum                                      #IntNumxpr
    | e=ident                                       #IdentExpr
    | op='(' e=expr ')'                             #ParenExpr
    | IF c=expr THEN t=expr ei+=elsif* ELSE e=expr  #IteExpr
    | op=(ADD|SUB) e=expr                           #UnopArithExpr
    |<assoc=right> l=expr op=CARRET r=expr          #PowerExpr
    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=(STAR|SLASH) r=expr     #MulDivExpr
    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=(ADD|SUB) r=expr        #AddSubExpr
    | l=expr op=(NEQ|EQ|LT|LE|GT|GE) r=expr         #RelExpr
    | op=NOT e=expr                                 #NotExpr
    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=AND r=expr              #AndExpr
    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=OR r=expr               #OrExpr
    |<assoc=left> l=expr op=IMPLIES r=expr          #ImpliesExpr
    ;

elsif 
locals [Elsif result]
    : op=ELSIF c=expr THEN t=expr 
    ;

ident
locals [Ident result]
    : id=IDENT
    ;

intNum
locals [IntNum result]
    : num=INT_NUM 
    ;

boolNum
locals [BoolNum result]
    : num=(TRUE | FALSE)
    ;

LT: '<' ;
LE: '<=' ;
GT: '>' ;
GE: '>=' ;
EQ: '=' ;
NEQ: '!=' ;
ADD: '+';
AND: 'and';
DEFINE: ':=';
CARRET: '^';
ELSE: 'else';
ELSIF: 'elsif';
FALSE: 'false';
IF: 'if';
IMPLIES: 'implies';
KW_BOOL: 'bool';
KW_INT: 'int';
NOT: 'not';
OR: 'or';
SLASH: '*';
STAR: '*';
SUB: '-';
THEN: 'then';
TRUE: 'true';
INT_NUM :'0' |[1-9][0-9]* ; 
IDENT:[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
WS: [ \t\f\r\n]+ -> skip;
//NL: '\r'? \n;
```

And a single Scala listener:

```
package toylang.parser.antlr
import toylang.ast._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

class Listener extends ToyLang2BaseListener {

  // stores the result of a successfull parse
  var result: Option[List[Stmt]] = None 

  override def exitBoolNum(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.BoolNumContext ): Unit = {
    ctx.result = BoolNum(ctx.num.getText)
  }

  override def exitImpliesExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.ImpliesExprContext ): Unit = {
    ctx.result = Implies (ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
  }

  override def exitAddSubExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.AddSubExprContext ): Unit = { 
    import ToyLang2Parser.{ADD, SUB}
    ctx.result = ctx.op.getType match {
      case ADD => Add(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
      case SUB => Sub(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
    }
  }

  override def exitIteExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.IteExprContext ): Unit = { 
    // using views to avoid creation of intermediate data
    val elsifList = ctx.ei.view  map { _.result } 
    ctx.result = Ite(ctx.c.result, ctx.t.result, elsifList.toList, ctx.e.result)
  }

  override def exitBoolNumExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.BoolNumExprContext ): Unit = {
    ctx.result = ctx.e.result
  }

  override def exitParenExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.ParenExprContext ): Unit = {
    ctx.result = ctx.e.result
  }

  override def exitPowerExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.PowerExprContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = Pow(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
  }

  override def exitIntNum(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.IntNumContext ): Unit = {
    ctx.result = IntNum(ctx.num.getText)
  }

  override def exitIdentExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.IdentExprContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = ctx.e.result
  }

  override def exitNotExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.NotExprContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = Not(ctx.e.result)
  }

  override def exitElsif(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.ElsifContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = Elsif(ctx.c.result, ctx.t.result)
  }

  override def exitBoolType(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.BoolTypeContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = BoolType
  }

  override def exitIdent(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.IdentContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = Ident(ctx.id.getText)
  }

  override def exitAndExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.AndExprContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = And(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
  }


  override def exitOrExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.OrExprContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = Or(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
}

  override def exitDef(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.DefContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = ctx.e.result
  }

  override def exitProgram(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.ProgramContext ): Unit = {
    ctx.result = (ctx.sl.view  map { _.result }).toList
    result = Some(ctx.result)

  }

  override def exitIntType(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.IntTypeContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = IntType
  }

  override def exitMulDivExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.MulDivExprContext ): Unit = { 
    import ToyLang2Parser.{STAR,SLASH}
    ctx.result = ctx.op.getType match {
      case STAR => Mul(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
      case SLASH => Div(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
    }
  }

  override def exitUnopArithExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.UnopArithExprContext ): Unit = { 
    import ToyLang2Parser.{ADD, SUB}
    ctx.result = ctx.op.getType match {
      case ADD => Plus(ctx.e.result)
      case SUB => Minus(ctx.e.result)
    }
  }

  override def exitIntNumxpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.IntNumxprContext ): Unit = { 
    ctx.result = ctx.e.result
  }

  override def exitDefStmt(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.DefStmtContext ): Unit = { 
    val d = ctx.d match {
      case null => None
      case e@_ => Some(e.result)
    }
    ctx.result = DefStmt(ctx.id.result, ctx.t.result, d)
  }

  override def exitRelExpr(ctx: ToyLang2Parser.RelExprContext ): Unit = { 
    import ToyLang2Parser.{NEQ,EQ,LT,LE,GT,GE}
    ctx.op.getType match {
      case NEQ => Neq(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
      case EQ => Eq(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
      case LT => Lt(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
      case LE => Le(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
      case GT => Gt(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
      case GE => Ge(ctx.l.result, ctx.r.result)
    }
  }
}
```

Last, instanciate antlr parser from scala and register scala listener:

```
package toylang.parser
import toylang.parser.antlr.{Listener, ToyLang2Lexer, ToyLang2Parser}
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.{ANTLRInputStream, CommonTokenStream}
import java.io.FileInputStream

class Parser2( arg: String ) {
  val input = new ANTLRInputStream(new FileInputStream(arg))
  val lexer = new ToyLang2Lexer(input)
  val tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer)
  val parser = new ToyLang2Parser(tokens)
  val listener = new Listener
  parser.addParseListener(listener)
  val prog = parser.program
  println (listener.result)
}
```

This cannot get simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your parser results to any data structure using the return value of your `parser.program` call. I have used this approach and find it much simpler than visitors or listeners, because this is the place where I actually expected the results of the parser.

Comment: yes the parse tree generated by antlr can be traversed to generate anything, however if the language is big there is a lot of boilerplate code to write, embedding the actions in the grammar allows to automatically generate this boilerplate, hence the solution I proposed. You can even use my translator to generate a single scala listener which can delegate actions to several different processors if you need to make multiple passes on the parse tree.